# How to prevent launch screen from loading automatically?

Tags: xcode, swift

I was wondering if someone could show me how to prevent my launch screen from going to my next screen automatically, unless I give permission by clicking a button that I would like to add to my launch screen.

Anyone any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The launch screen is non-interactive and disappears as soon as the app has launched. Either have a plain black one, and make your initial view controller have the launch content instead, or duplicate the content.

Note that a pointless button press as the initial user action will be bad user experience and may be frowned on by the review team, though who knows nowadays.